# What is the state of the art tooling for Spring context analysis at runtime?

Tags: java, spring

Assuming you have a rather big Spring application (including sources) at hand and you want to gather all kinds of information about the contexts beans at runtime : bean names, types, classes, child application contexts, property values, annotations, proxies structure etc.

What kind of tools would one use to find out ?

Answer (score 1):

I used to maintain https://github.com/krosenvold/spring-context-analyzer, which detects problematic scope transitions. might need some adjudtments for spring versions >3

Comment: I have seen your project at github. From the quick look I had, it seemed to me it is not quite what I was looking for. Thanks for mentioning it anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SpringSource is coming up with a solution called "Live Beans Graph" which is supposed to be shipping with STS 3.1. https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2810 has some details.